# Difference between GetWindowsDirectory and GetSystemWindowsDirectory?

Tags: c++, winapi, terminal-services

I'm trying to test the different system paths that is supposed to be returned by [GetWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetSystemWindowsDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs on a console and via a remote connection. According to the documentation:

> With Terminal Services, the GetSystemWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of the system Windows directory, while the GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of a Windows directory that is private for each user. On a single-user system, GetSystemWindowsDirectory is the same as GetWindowsDirectory.

I can't seem to see any difference. They both return "C:\Windows" in either.

Can someone explain why am I not seeing what the documentation announced for the terminal services?

**EDIT:** Here's a little C++ code sample I was running:

```
//Check if RDP session
BOOL bRDP = FALSE;
DWORD dwSessID = -1;
::ProcessIdToSessionId(::GetCurrentProcessId(), &dwSessID);
DWORD dwSz;
LPTSTR ppBuffer = NULL;
if(WTSQuerySessionInformation(NULL, dwSessID, WTSClientProtocolType, &ppBuffer, &dwSz))
{
    bRDP = *(USHORT*)ppBuffer == 2;
    WTSFreeMemory(ppBuffer);
}

_tprintf(_T("%s\n"), !bRDP ? _T("Console Session") : _T("RDP Session"));

//Get system folder
TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH * 2];

buff[0] = 0;
GetSystemWindowsDirectory(buff, SIZEOF(buff));
_tprintf(_T("Sysfolder1: %s\n"), buff);

buff[0] = 0;
GetWindowsDirectory(buff, SIZEOF(buff));
_tprintf(_T("Sysfolder2: %s\n"), buff);
```

And here's the output I'm getting from a remote desktop session:

```
RDP Session
Sysfolder1: C:\WINDOWS
Sysfolder2: C:\WINDOWS
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it obvious what you are asking. If you had included this information, that would have helped.

Comment: did you set the IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE flag when you linked your test app? The docs say that if set, both APIs return the same. Only if it's not set you'll get different results.

Comment: @Stefan: No, I don't even know what it is and how to edit it. Maybe VS does it by default? Although how would it know that I'd run it through a remote desktop connection? I'm also not sure if that message in MSDN applies to Windows Server 2003, because that's where I test it.

Comment: Have you tried to call GetWindowsDirectory in RDP session ? If I understand documentation correctly if you run it from separate session (not console) you will get path to  \%homedrive%\windows

Comment: @Zilog I updated my original question with the code and the output. I was expecting something different from the output. Maybe there something not set up on my test AD then?

Comment: You typically need to be running Windows Server Terminal Services Edition in order to see a difference.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Wow, I didn't even know such SKU existed. I can't seem to find it through Google either...

Comment: Looks like it got renamed to "Remote Desktop Services" in 2003.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I do have Terminal Server installed on this Windows Server 2003 that I'm testing it on. Take a look: http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/term_srv.jpg

Comment: As @Stefan noted, if you set the /TSAWARE flag, then `GetWindowsDirectory` returns the real Windows directory instead of the fake one.

Comment: @RaymondChen: One actually needs to disable this flag. I posted it with a screenshot below. So thanks everyone who helped to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @RaymondChen and @Stefan, **only** if one specifies the [/TSAWARE:NO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cfys9z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) linker option in the application settings, you will see the difference in the output:
[image]

In this case I got this output:

```
RDP Session
Sysfolder1: C:\WINDOWS
Sysfolder2: C:\Documents and Settings\RemoteUserA\WINDOWS
```

Comment: Looks like Raymond queued up an article when he saw this question - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/07/23/10544433.aspx